# Differentiability of a function and its roots

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Suppose we know that $g$ if thrice differentiable and that $g(x) = 1000$ has exactly 10 distinct solution. Then is it always true that $g'''(x)$ has atleast 7 roots? In general if a function $g$ is $n$ times differentiable, and the function has k distinct solutions, then $g^{(n)}$ has atleast $k-n$ roots (given $k-n \geq 0$)?

Comment: Yes, apply Rolle' theorem $3$ times to $f(x)=g(x)-1000$

Comment: I guess you are talking about real roots.  If you mean complex roots, you will have to do something other than Rolle's theorem.

Comment: im talking about real roots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean considering only real solutions. Let $f(x)=g(x)-1000$. $f(x)=0$ has $10$ solutions (Number them $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_{10}$). That is, $f(\alpha_1)=f(\alpha_2)=...=f(\alpha_{10})=0$.

Now, applying Rolle's theorem on $[\alpha_i, \alpha_{i+1}]$ implies that $\exists$ at least one $b_i$ satisfying  $\alpha_i\lt b_i\lt \alpha_{i+1}$ for each $i\in {1,2,3,...,9}$, such that $f'(b_i)=0$. Thus, $f'(x)=0$ has atleast nine solutions.

Repeat the same process on $f'(x)=0$ to deduce that $f''(x)=0$ has atleast $8$ solutions. And finally repeat the same process on $f'''(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=(x-c)^2g(x) \Rightarrow f^{'}(x)=2(x-c)g(x)+ (x-c)^2g^{'}(x)$$